# How to break video into Frames without Increase in Size in OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a video that is 478Mb big, and that I want to split into png's, but when I tried, each frame became around 2Mb (there are 39.5k frames) and the result was over 60Gb in size.
Is there a way to do it without this massive increase in size? My code is below.

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
success = True
frame = 0
while success:
    success, img = vidcap.read()
    png_name = videoname + '_frame_' + str(frame) + '.png'
    cv2.imwrite(FRAMES_FOLDER + '/' + png_name, img)
    frame += 1
vidcap.release()
```

Comment: Video compression works by sending a full frame then a number (20, 50, 60?) of ‘difference’ frames before the next full frame - this is (as you are discovering) much more efficient than encoding each full frame. Saving to lossy jpeg format files is likely to be a lot smaller than lossless png and as the source is m/jpeg video there’s not much quality to be compromised by using jpeg compared to png.

Comment: That does make it smaller, but still over 10Gb in total.

Comment: “Thanks, Barny you helped me make the files 1/6th the size”. Goes to show how effective video compression is. You aren’t likely to get much better but it would be nice to be surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying @barny 's answer. Seems like the best that can be done is to use JPEG instead.

> Video compression works by sending a full frame then a number (20, 50, 60?) of ‘difference’ frames before the next full frame - this is (as you are discovering) much more efficient than encoding each full frame. Saving to lossy jpeg format files is likely to be a lot smaller than lossless png and as the source is m/jpeg video there’s not much quality to be compromised by using jpeg compared to png.